# with and closing of files in Python

Tags: python, with-statement, urlopen, contextmanager

I have read, that file opened like this is closed automatically when leaving the with block:

```
with open("x.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    do something with data
```

yet when opening from web, I need this:

```
from contextlib import closing
from urllib.request import urlopen

with closing(urlopen('http://www.python.org')) as page:
    for line in page:
        print(line)
```

why and what is the difference? (I am using Python3)

Comment: I was about to suggest that someone should file a docs bug on `contextlib` for this, and that if it's not you whoever it is should credit you… but before I could finish, Martijn already filed the bug, with the link back here. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The details get a little technical, so let's start with the simple version:

Some types know how to be used in a `with` statement. File objects, like what you get back from `open`, are an example of such a type. As it turns out, the objects that you get back from `urllib.request.urlopen`, are *also* an example of such a type, so your second example could be written the same way as the first.

But some types don't know how to be used in a `with` statement. The `closing` function is designed to wrap such types—as long as they have a `close` method, it will call their `close` method when you exit the `with` statement.

Of course some types don't know how to be used in a `with` statement, and also can't be used with `closing` because their cleanup method isn't named `close` (or because cleaning them up is more complicated than just closing them). In that case, you need to write a custom context manager. But even that isn't usually that hard.

---

In technical terms:

A `with` statement requires a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers), an object with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. It will call the `__enter__` method, and give you the value returned by that method in the `as` clause, and it will then call the `__exit__` method at the end of the `with` statement.

File objects inherit from [`io.IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#i-o-base-classes), which is a context manager whose `__enter__` method returns itself, and whose `__exit__` calls `self.close()`.

The object returned by [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) is (assuming an `http` or `https` URL) an [`HTTPResponse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects), which, as the docs say, "can be used with a `with` statement".

The [`closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) function:

> Return a context manager that closes thing upon completion of the block. This is basically equivalent to:

```
@contextmanager
def closing(thing):
    try:
        yield thing
    finally:
        thing.close()
```

---

It's not always 100% clear in the docs which types are context managers and which types aren't. Especially since there's been a major drive since 3.1 to make everything that could be a context manager into one (and, for that matter, to make everything that's mostly-file-like into an actual `IOBase` if it makes sense), but it's still not 100% complete as of 3.4.

You can always just try it and see. If you get an `AttributeError: __exit__`, then the object isn't usable as a context manager. If you think it should be, file a bug suggesting the change. If you don't get that error, but the docs don't mention that it's legal, file a bug suggesting the docs be updated.

Comment: Wonderful explanation, 8 years later.

Answer (score 8):

You don't. `urlopen('http://www.python.org')` returns a context manager too:

```
with urlopen('http://www.python.org') as page:
```

This is documented on the [`urllib.request.urlopen()` page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen):

> For ftp, file, and data urls and requests explicity handled by legacy `URLopener` and `FancyURLopener` classes, this function returns a `urllib.response.addinfourl` object **which can work as context manager** [...].

Emphasis mine. For HTTP responses, [`http.client.HTTPResponse()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse) is returned, which also is a context manager:

> The response is an iterable object and **can be used in a with statement**.

The [*Examples* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples) also uses the object as a context manager:

> As the python.org website uses utf-8 encoding as specified in it’s meta tag, we will use the same for decoding the bytes object.
>
> ```
> >>> with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org/') as f:
> ...     print(f.read(100).decode('utf-8'))
> ...
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
> "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtm
> ```

Objects returned by `open()` are [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) too; they implement the special methods [`object.__enter__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__) and [`object.__exit__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__).

The [`contextlib.closing()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) uses an example with `urlopen()` that is out of date; in Python 2 the predecessor for `urllib.request.urlopen()` did not produce a context manager and you needed to use that tool to auto-close the connection with a context manager. This was fixed with issues [5418](http://bugs.python.org/issue5418) and [12365](http://bugs.python.org/issue12365), but that example was not updated. I created [issue 22755](http://bugs.python.org/issue22755) asking for a different example.

Comment: I was just about to write this :-).  the key is that the docs say that it returns a "file-like" object.  If it can't be used as a context manager, it's not actually file-like.

Comment: but why is this example in the python docs, then? https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html

Comment: @nekomimi: a holdover from Python 2 probably, where the object was not a context manager.

Comment: The quoted docs aren't the relevant part. He's got an `http` url, which doesn't return an `addinfourl`, it returns an `HTTPResponse`. Of course those can _also_ be used as context managers.

Comment: @abarnert: as always, it is a little more complex. Thanks for correcting me, updated.

Comment: I don't think `HTTPResponse` is documented to be an `IOBase`, although that's pretty strongly implied by having methods like `readinto`. But [it is definitely documented to be a context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects).

Comment: @abarnert: argh, I searched for 'context manager' and 'contextmanager' and '\_\_enter__'. I did not search for 'with statement'..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think most things turned into context managers post-3.1 use the "can be used in a with statement" language, while most older ones use the "is a context manager" language.

Comment: @abarnert: Interesting, is the context manager terminology being deprecated?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I don't think so. My guess is that whoever did most of the work in the big push post-3.1 thought it would be more helpful to just say "can be used in a with statement" than to say something that some Python users don't understand and have to link to the glossary, and nobody really argued about it?